# Table model in empty table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am creating a Java Swing application which displays a window with a table where the user can insert or delete selected elements stored in an array. For this table I have created a table model class extending the DefaultTableModel class. 
The problem arises when all the elements have been deleted from the table, as a null pointer exception is thrown. Does anyone know a quick solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: seeing the code around where the null pointer is thrown (and an indication which line triggers the exception) would help in identifying the solution.

Comment: The DefaultTableModel works fine with 0 rows. So the problem is with your custom code. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I usually handle such model-view conversion anomalies by [*Using Custom Renderers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). For example:

```
setText((value == null) ? "" : formatter.format(value));
```